# Incorrect output and warning message ''Makes pointer from int ''

Tags: c

I was writing a c program whose job was to convert a Celsius temperate to Fahrenheit, and vice-versa. I wanted my user to provide input in the form

```
 double, char
```

Where the character would be either a 'F' for Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion, or 'C' for Celsius to Fahrenheit conversions. 
I wrote this program to do it.
The Program

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main( )
 {
     char in[10];
     int i;
     printf("Welcome to the Tempurate Conversion Enter a ");
     scanf("%s %d", i, &in);
     printf(i);
     printf(in);
     return 0;
 }
```

When I compile this program I get this warning:
The Warning

```
 CtoF.c: In function 'main':
 CtoF.c:8:4: warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer w
 ithout a cast [enabled by default]
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/stdio.h:294:37: note:
 expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

I when ran to the program and gave this input:
The Input

```
 3 C
```

and got this output:
The Output

```
 3@
```

I want to know the meaning of the warning message and what I can to do to fix it.

Comment: `scanf("%s %d", i, &in);` -> `scanf("%d %s", i, in);` (note the order of format specifiers and the removed ampersand symbol - that's not how you use the address-of operator.)

Comment: @H2CO3; Why you removed `&` from `i`?

Comment: @haccks Because I made a typo. I only wanted to remove it from before `in`. (Thanks for pointing it out.)

Comment: @H2CO3; `i` is `int` and you should have to pass its address to `scanf`.

Comment: But hey, why is this such a great question that it got +3? OP obviously didn't even bother reading a basic C tutorial...

Comment: @haccks And you think I don't know that? "I only wanted to remove it from before `in`"...

Comment: @H2CO3; I know you did this by mistake. That was just for confirmation :)

Comment: This is just a classic case of [RTFM](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: @H2CO3 I expect the reason that this was upvoted so much is because the question is written clearly and because it contains a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with format specifiers in `scanf` and `printf`.

```
 scanf("%s %d", i, &in);
```

should be

```
 scanf("%d %s", &i, in);
```

And

```
 printf(i);
 printf(in);
```

should be

```
printf("%d", i);
printf("%s", in);
```

---

*And a side note:*

> I wanted my user to provide input in the form `double, char`

For this you should have to change `int i` to

```
 double i;
```

and conversion specifier `%d` to `%lf` in `scanf`:

```
scanf("%lf %s", &i, in);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `printf` statement is wrong.

`printf` expects a char array like `char in[10]`. However you are passing an integer. `int i`.

The warnings informs you that because `printf` expects a pointer parameter and you are passing an integer, this integer gets cast to a pointer.

So if your integer has the value of 100 it now tries to read from memory address located at 100 and keeps dumping the memory untill a `\0` character/value is found

Answer (score 0):

printf works in the following way:

the first argument to printf tells how many arguments are expected

```
printf( "%d", n );
```

tells that one argument is expected (an int pointer)

```
printf( "%d %d", n, m );
```

tells that there are two arguments so your syntax is wrong